# Interactively create PDF file from javascript generated html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

I have a webpage with an interactive paged grid rendered using javascript. i.e. it's a grid that pulls in a number of rows at a time through MVC ajax call and have controls for going forward, backwards or jumping to a particular page. It is a fairly large grid (potentially millions of rows) and can display a number of different datasets. I would like to be able to generate a PDF containing a snapshot of each and every page from this dynamic grid. All the libraries I have looked at transfering html to pdf have all been static, anybody know of a good fast library to transfer interactive/dynamic javascript generated html to pdf? I am willing to do this at the server layer as well, if it is possible to import the .css skins used to create the grid on the webpage, to make the look similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that fits your needs, but I used

http://www.tcpdf.org/

some time ago, and it worked quite good. But no idea how good it works with javascript and stuff.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm using ASP.NET MVC not PHP, not sure how that would fit in.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I ended up using LocalReport From Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.